# In monodroid enviroment how do I get the Context outside of the View

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to load an asset and the only way I can see to do that is with

```
Context.Assets.Open();
```

I don't see a way to get access to Context without passing it around. I really don't want to pass it around

Comment: How about using **getApplicationContext()** ?

Comment: can't find it in the documentation at http://docs.xamarin.com/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
Application.Context.Assests.Open()
```

is what I was looking for. For some reason I just couldn't see it.